# .NET Core - Image resources not included / compiled in library

Tags: c#, .net-core, resources, .net-standard

I would like to include some PNG image files into an assembly (.dll) for use in a WPF application. We previously targeted .NET Framework 4.8 which worked fine but since migrating the project to .NET Standard 2.1 the resources are being ignored.

Using the .NET Framework 4.8 does store the resources as wanted, which means that there is a [AssemblyName].g.resources entry containing a directory-like structure with the images in it. When switching to "netstandard2.1" as target platform, the resources are not included.

The .csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <Win32Resource />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\AssemblyInfo.App.cs" Link="Properties\AssemblyInfo.App.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="**\*.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The expected result is a resource hierarchy compiled into the library file so that the images can be accessed directly from .xaml. We did this successfuly with .NET Framework as target platform but it won't work with .NET Standard 2.1 or .NET Core 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you just need to change

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
```

in your project file.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2258) are the details and root cause of this problem.